# Android: Special url to open Marketplace to a specific app?

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a url format available such that clicking on the url will
open the Android (Gphone) Marketplace to a particular app's page for installation?

Does it work with the 'current' Android OS ver in the wild?

Eg, can I put something on my customized Android website better than

1. Please open the Marketplace application,
2. search for FBReader
3. then install it

The app that I want to point people to is the epub reader, FBReader
http://www.fbreader.org/FBReaderJ/

Answer (score 4):

Based on the info here:  http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html

It looks like you're looking for this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Where the id= is followed by the package name of the app you wish to link to directly in the store.

To find out the package name, download and install the app on your device, then run

```
adb shell
```

and use the command:

```
pm list packages -f
```

that will list everything you have installed on the device, you should be able to find the app you are looking for pretty easily.

Comment: The problem is that this actually opens the market app in the same app running this code, what i want is to open the market place as a separate app... any ideas ?

Comment: @code4jhon, what do you mean by "in the same app"? It opens the PlayStore app.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as a standard HTML anchor tag:

https://market.android.com/search?q=pname:com.google.earth

thus, for the "pname" parameter, you (Larry K) would likely use:

https://market.android.com/search?q=pname:
[ org (dot) geometerplus (dot) zlibrary (dot) ui (dot) android ]

...similar to:

market://search?q=pname:com.google.earth

Yes?

Answer (score 0):

I looked around your website and didn't see that you had figured this out for your site so I thought I'd share what I learned recently.
If you create a link to:
market://search?q=org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android

This will link directly to your app in the marketplace.

Comment: No, that links to a search that returns a single result. `market://details?id=org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android` links to the details.